# kotlin: how to use KProperty2?

Tags: kotlin

I understand that `KProperty1` represents a property on a class, such as `MyClass::myProperty`.

I'm having trouble understand how [KProperty2](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-property2/) should be used, or even what the concrete use case is for that pattern?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as documentation states for properties that take **two** receivers like extension property declared in a class.

Do note that calling extension functions and properties declared within class has be done within that class itself or through scoping functions (as done in sample below with `run {}`):

Example:

```
data class Foo(val tag : String) {
    val Int.echo
        get() = "Im extension on $this within ${this@Foo}"
}

fun propTest(){
    val foo = Foo("Baz")

    foo.run {
        println(5.echo)    // prints Im extension on 5 within Foo(tag=Baz)
    }

    val tagRef : KProperty1<Foo, String> = Foo::tag
    val echoRef : KProperty2<Foo, Int, String> = Foo::class.declaredMemberExtensionProperties.first() as KProperty2<Foo, Int, String>

    println(echoRef.get(foo, 7))  // prints Im extension on 7 within Foo(tag=Baz)
}
```

I don't know if it's possible to directly reference those extensions (`Int::echo` within class scope just causes error) that's why I used [`declaredMemberExtensionProperties`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/declared-member-extension-properties.html) (which is actually a `List<Kproperty2<Foo, *, *>>`) to fetch it.